# Powershell - check if a CD is in CD-ROM drive

Tags: powershell, wmi, hardware, wmi-query

Is this possible?

My first guess would be something like:

`C:> Get-WmiObject Win32_CDROMDrive`

But when I tried this, it only tells me `Caption`, `Drive`, `Manufacturer`,`VolumeName`

No information on whether or not there is a CD in the disc drive.

Comment: `[IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | where { $_.DriveType -eq 'CDRom' -and $_.IsReady }` (based on C# answers)

Comment: Personally, I find questions like this misleading.  Is there a cd in the drive, yes, when you checked, but 1 second later, the user ejected it.  Why not just try to read (or write) to the drive or whatever you want to do, and handle failures?

Comment: @KoryGill Reading or writing to the CD is beside the point. The end goal is to check to see if there is media inside the drive or not.

Comment: What problem are you solving by getting the answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this information by

```
(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive -Property *).MediaLoaded
```

You can see what properties are available for that WMI class by

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive -Property * | Get-Member
```

and more detailed documentation from

```
Get-WMIHelp -Class Win32_CDROMDrive
```

In general, you will find that liberal use of the `Get-Help`, `Get-Member`, `Get-Command`, and `Get-WMIHelp` cmdlets will provide you with a great deal of information, and possibly eliminate the need to ask questions like this here and wait for an answer that may or may not come.

Comment: Ah, should've tried `-Properties *`. I always forget there may be properties it is not reporting

Comment: Get-WMIHelp is not a standard PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: True. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/09/24/get-wmihelp-amp-search-wmihelp/ and https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1440 - I've had them on my system for so long that I'd forgotten they were add-ons.